Removing stale ProviderAuthorization entry which is no longer needed
We have one stale provider auth in our manifest. We no longer require that provider auth as those flows are deprecated and also corresponding app is tracked for delete.
When we try to update the manifest we are getting the below error, PR https://armmanifest.visualstudio.com/One/_git/Manifest/pullrequest/9129
An existing provider authorization cannot be removed. Please add back the authorization for application id '157638eb-a5cb-4c10-af42-2d6759eb1871
We are acknowledging here that there is no customer impact and breaking changes due to this. How we should proceed for the next steps?
Thanks,
Subba

Remove the deprecated provider authorization from the manifest and proceed with the update, ensuring no customer impact or breaking changes.
